# React component not refreshing when state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that takes an array as a parameter. From this array it generates a list. In the parent component, the array is a state variable and whenever that state variable is updated I want the changes to be reflected in the child component.

What's happening is the component is being rendered once but none of the changes are being shown.

**App.js:**

```
import heatData from "./config/heats.json";

export default function App() {
    const [selectedHeat, setSelectedHeat] = useState(heatData.heats.find((x) => x.heatNumber === 1));
    const [selectedHeatNumber, setSelectedHeatNumber] = useState(1);

    const heats = heatData.heats;
    const heatEvents = ["EventA", "EventB", "EventC", "EventD"];

    useEffect(() => {
        const _selectedHeat = heatData.heats.find((x) => x.heatNumber === selectedHeatNumber);
        setSelectedHeat(_selectedHeat);
    }, [selectedHeatNumber]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {heats.map((heat, i) => (
                        <li onClick={() => setSelectedHeatNumber(heat.heatNumber)}>
                            Heat #{heat.heatNumber}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>

                <div>
                    {heatEvents.map((event, i) => (
                        // This renders once but when selectedHeat changes it doesnt re-render
                        <EventCard athletes={selectedHeat.athletes} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**heats.json that's being imported:**

```
{
    "heats": [
        {
            "heatNumber": 1,
            "athletes": ["PersonA, PersonB, PersonC"]
        },
        {
            "heatNumber": 2,
            "athletes": ["PersonD, PersonE, PersonF"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**EventCard.js:**

```
export default function EventCard({ athletes }) {
    const [userPrediction, setUserPrediction] = useState([...athletes]);
    
    // Add methods to manipulate userPrediction

    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {userPrediction.map((athlete, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td>{athlete}</td>
                        <td>Up</td>
                        <td>Down</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Here's the process:

- Import `heats.json`
- Loop over `heats` to produce a menu which, when clicked, sets the current heat
- Print the list of events and pass in the athletes for the current heat

The problem is that clicking the button changes the heat but the athletes in EventCard do not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this `useEffect` to your `EventCard.js` component, because you are setting the `state` with athletes only first time and the state is not updating when the props change, so you should keep track the change in `props` and then update `state` accordingly. [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-stonebraker-x5ec9?file=/src/EventCard.js:244-317)

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUserPrediction([...athletes]);
  }, [athletes]);
```

Or you can use `athletes` props directly like:

```
{athletes.map((athlete, i) => (
          <tr key={i}>
            <td>{athlete}</td>
            <td>Up</td>
            <td>Down</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
```